# Display attribute in JComboBox and register another attribute

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have a JComboBox and I must show the designation of the product, and each has a code designation,
in my database I have to register the product code but in the Combo I must show the designation, how should I do to display the designation in the combo but save its code in the database?

this is my code for return code and designation

```
    public ResultSet GetDesignation(JComboBox des)
{
ResultSet rs1 = null;


try {

conn=con.Connect();

stmt = conn.createStatement();
String rq1 = "SELECT designation, idproduit  FROM  produit";

rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(rq1);
while (rs1.next()) {
des.addItem(rs1.getString(1));

}
stmt.close();

conn.close();

}  catch (SQLException e) { 
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{


return rs1;
}
}
```

and this is the code which i get the idproduct (code)

```
m.GetDesignation(des);
 int designation=Integer.parseInt(des.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of direct population of `JComboBox`, create something like a Product class and in each iteration of your `while` loop extract id and product's name from `ResultSet` and set it to properties of Product instance. Add that Product instance in some collection like `ArrayList` and use it to populate your `JComboBox`:

```
public class Product {

    private int idProduct;

    private String name;


    public Product(int idProduct, String name) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(int idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Set `DefaultComboBoxModel` for your `JComboBox` and add data to your model:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class ComboDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JComboBox<Product> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Product> defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        comboBox.setModel(defaultComboBoxModel);
        defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(new Product(1, "Apples"));
        defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(new Product(2, "Oranges"));

        comboBox.addItemListener(e -> {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                Product product = (Product) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(product.getName() + " ::: " + product.getIdProduct());
            }
        });

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, comboBox);
    }
}
```

Add `ItemListener` on `JComboBox` and use `getSelectedItem` to obtain a `Product` from that `JComboBox`. So basically, in this case, your `JComboBox` contains `Product` items with all their properties instead of `String's` as in your case.